# Relationship Between Basis for Topology and Generating Set?

Tags: general-topology

So there is the notion of the *basis for a topology* $\tau$ on $X$ which is a set $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets such that every element of $\tau$ can be written as the union of some elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

There another notion which is more akin to a free group, which is the *topology generated by a set* e.g. given a set $S \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ the topology generated by $S$ is the smallest topology on $X$ such that the elements of $S$ are open sets.

Obviously, a generating set is not always a basis for the topology generated by it because a topology must contain the entire space and there is no guarantee that an arbitrary set of generators will cover the space. So my question is: *under what conditions is a set $S$ also a basis for the topology generated by $S$*?

Answer (score 3):

1. Let $V$ be any family of subsets of $X.$ Then $V\cup \{X\}$ is a sub-base for a topology on $X.$ A sub-base for  a topology $T$ on $X$ is a set  $U \subset T$ such that $\{\cap V: V\in [U]^{<\omega}\}$ is a base for $T,$ where $[U]^{<\omega}$ denotes the set of all finite subsets of $U.$

2.A family $W$ of subsets of $X$ is a base for a topology iff (i): $\cup W=X$ (Every member of $X$ belongs to at least one member of $W$) and (ii) Whenever $p\in w_1\cap w_2$ with $w_1, w_2\in W,$ there exists $w_3\in W$ with $p\in w_3\subset (w_1\cap w_2).$

Note that a base for a topology $T$ is also a sub-base for $T.$

Note that if $W$ is a family of subsets of $X$ satisfying (i) and if $w_1\cap w_2\in W$ whenever $w_1,w_2\in W,$ then $W$ also satisfies (ii).